# A dementia that develops ONLY in humans under 25 years old

Tags: diseases, health

In my story, there is a 24 years old human who, despite being an adultescent (aged between 18 to 24 years old), shows Alzheimer's-like symptoms: he forgot the name of his best friend forever, he is as aggressive as a wild boar, and he talks in the third singular person without conjugating (in other words, he talks like the Hulk from Disney's Marvel Multiverse).

So, I wonder if there is a real life disease that resembles Alzheimer's disease, but instead of affecting humans who are more than 65 years old, has an age of onset that is less than 25 years old.

Comment: Adultescent should probably be adolescent. (Latin *[adolesco](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/adolesco), adolescere, adolêvi, adultum* "to grow up, to mature", present participle *adolescens, -tis* "which is growing up", from the same root \**oleo* "to grow" from which in English we have the borrowed word *indolent*. The Indo-European root is [\**h₂el-*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/h₂el-), from which English has "old".) (I was triggered because the ending -ent suggest a Latin present participle, but those cannot be formed from the stem of the perfectum.)

Comment: So early onset dementia isn't something you've heard of then?

Comment: Puberty? Loss of verbal communications skills, emotional outbursts, inability to recognize loved ones or complete simple, previously well remembered tasks, roaming, lack of focus etc etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Frame challenge:

#### Brain damage

If it is only to afflict one person, Why not just go for severe head injury that caused brain damage? Brain damage can cause all the desired symptoms.  Brain damage can be from something as simple as: slipped, fell, head hit a rock.

Stroke, causing brain damage. How did the clot that got to brain form?  Family trait, severe injury that caused internal bleeding, would easiest to explain. Interaction with unusual sea life(more variety of toxins then land based) or insect. Or perhaps injection of a weird fungus.

Answer (score 3):

The obvious candidates are [Creutzfeldt–Jakob disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creutzfeldt%E2%80%93Jakob_disease), which can strike at any age, and the [Adult-dominant form of Neuronal Ceroid Lipofuscinosis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neuronal_ceroid_lipofuscinosis#Adult_dominant_form).

Either matches your requirements, but both are fatal within a year or so of the appearance of symptoms.

Answer (score 1):

Its not a disease but there are similarities between what you asking for and what happens when children are raised by wild animals but rescued before they reach adulthood.

There are certain neural pathways which can only be developed by children up to a certain age and when wild children are rescued they are usually unable to reliably repeat cognitive techniques such as naming objects, people or repeating their own names - even though they acutely aware of the concept they are unable to articulate. Another similar deficiency is being able to understanding what a fork is, being able to name it but being unable to recall how to use it. The experience is pretty harrowing for the rescued wild child and their caretakers and the rescued children are recorded as going into animal-like fits of rage when they are unable to repeat "human" concepts.

Also the rescued wild children tend to deteriorate when separated from the caretakers who taught them human etiquette :(

If you run with this, just lower the age at which your character was rescued to limit the amount of mental damage the existential shift in worlds did to him.

Answer (score 1):

Metachromatic Leukodystrophy isn’t far off. It generally presents at a younger age, but my niece was diagnosed at 20. The doctors didn’t even think to test for it at first because she was “too old”, though looking back now, she was showing signs much earlier and we all just wrote them off as her being a typical irresponsible and immature teen.